# How to speed up vim's buffer open?

Tags: vim

How i can speed up buffer open for the first time?
I find myself often use ctrl-p and load is very slow.
Also rails.vim navigation is terrible.

[my vimrc](https://github.com/andi3731/vimfiles)

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit.
AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5000+ × 2,
2GB RAM

Comment: What does ctrl-p do? Because, you know, by default it doesn't open buffers. It does completion. Also: the correct question is not how to speed it up, the question is how to _not_ slow it down. Plugins are slowing it down. Remove or configure you plugins.

Comment: Setting an explicit Ruby path via `let g:ruby_path = "/usr/bin/ruby"` solved it for me.

Comment: @sehe thanks.

I'll take a look at my plugins and try to remove ones that I don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Vim versions (also Ubuntu 13.04) have the `--startuptime {fname}` command-line argument.

> ```
>   This can be used to find out where time is spent while loading
>   your .vimrc, plugins and opening the first file.
> ```

Also / alternatively, look into `:help profiling`. That (with a bit of Vim knowledge) can tell you the exact hotspots in your setup and plugins.

It also helps to observe whether the slow startup depends on the *filetype* or a large file *size* (or whether it's slow in general).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open a very large file, you can disable the swap/recovery file with the -n option.